# Reading quoted/escaped arguments correctly from a string

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm encountering an issue passing an argument to a command in a Bash script.

poc.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARGS='"hi there" test'
./swap ${ARGS}
```

swap:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "${2}" "${1}"
```

The current output is:

```
there" "hi
```

Changing only poc.sh (as I believe swap does what I want it to correctly), how do I get poc.sh to pass "hi there" and test as two arguments, with "hi there" having no quotes around it?

Comment: This is the topic of BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: inverse operation: [Correctly quote array that is being passed indirectly via another command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518012/correctly-quote-array-that-is-being-passed-indirectly-via-another-command)

Answer (score 25):

#### A Few Introductory Words

If at all possible, *don't* use shell-quoted strings as an input format.

- It's hard to parse consistently: Different shells have different extensions, and different non-shell implementations implement different subsets (see the deltas between `shlex` and `xargs` below).
- It's hard to programmatically generate. ksh and bash have `printf '%q'`, which will generate a shell-quoted string with contents of an arbitrary variable, but no equivalent exists to this in the POSIX sh standard.
- It's easy to parse *badly*. Many folks consuming this format use `eval`, which has substantial security concerns.

NUL-delimited streams are a far better practice, as they can accurately represent *any* possible shell array or argument list with no ambiguity whatsoever.

---

#### xargs, with bashisms

If you're getting your argument list from a human-generated input source using shell quoting, you might consider using `xargs` to parse it. Consider:

```
array=( )
while IFS= read -r -d ''; do
  array+=( "$REPLY" )
done < <(xargs printf '%s\0' <<<"$ARGS")

swap "${array[@]}"
```

...will put the parsed content of `$ARGS` into the array `array`. If you wanted to read from a file instead, substitute `<filename` for `<<<"$ARGS"`.

---

#### xargs, POSIX-compliant

If you're trying to write code compliant with POSIX sh, this gets trickier. (I'm going to assume file input here for reduced complexity):

```
# This does not work with entries containing literal newlines; you need bash for that.
run_with_args() {
  while IFS= read -r entry; do
    set -- "$@" "$entry"
  done
  "$@"
}
xargs printf '%s\n' <argfile | run_with_args ./swap
```

---

These approaches are safer than running `xargs ./swap <argfile` inasmuch as it will throw an error if there are more or longer arguments than can be accommodated, rather than running excess arguments as separate commands.

---

#### Python shlex -- rather than xargs -- with bashisms

If you need more accurate POSIX sh parsing than `xargs` implements, consider using the Python `shlex` module instead:

```
shlex_split() {
  python -c '
import shlex, sys
for item in shlex.split(sys.stdin.read()):
    sys.stdout.write(item + "\0")
'
}
while IFS= read -r -d ''; do
  array+=( "$REPLY" )
done < <(shlex_split <<<"$ARGS")
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with `ARGS="\"a\\\"b\" c"`? Error reported *xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option*

Comment: Fair point -- `xargs` indeed doesn't honor POSIX sh behavior in that case. Updating with an alternative using the Python 2's `shlex.split()` function instead.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to put the OP back on the right track: if OP needs such a thing, then their design is obviously wrong. Unless OP is writing a shell (or a cli), in which case the choice of language is wrong. Either way, OP is doing it wrong.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, ...in theory, I agree. In practice, folks tend to be given requirements that don't make sense (or need compatibility with longstanding systems/practices -- there are a *ton* of legacy startup scripts for Java apps floating around that rely on `eval`ing argument lists given in shell-quoted form), and there's value in being able to make the best of a bad situation... though certainly, "don't do that" ought to be part of the advice given.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, ...I've edited in an appropriate introduction.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy curious what you would do if the command (`./swap` in the above example) needed to read from stdin as well, as you have captured it for `run_with_args`?

Comment: @deitch, the easy thing is to use a different FD. `3< <(...)` will feed the input on FD 3 rather than 0, then one can `IFS= read -r entry <&3`. With bash 4.1 or later, FD numbers can be dynamically assigned and used from variables (thus also passed on command line arguments &c), making this even easier.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of that. Nice. I am using posix sh, so the bashism won't work. I ended up doing a variant on your solution, see this gist https://gist.github.com/deitch/e93f3bab0f1d535f9b8bcec8459f7f79

Comment: That's buggy, unfortunately, but almost necessarily so with POSIX sh. `args="$@"` is storing your array in a string, so it necessarily loses information about argument boundaries. See `OPTS='a "*" d'` for a pathological case.

Comment: (If you *intend* to collapse an argument list to a string, better to use `args="$*"` to be more explicit about that intent).

Comment: ...Similarly, `OPTS='-name "*.txt"'` will differ in its behavior based on which files are in your local directory and locally set shell options (any equivalent to `nullglob` or `failglob` will cause the `*.txt` to be removed from the option list entirely).

Answer (score 5):

Embedded quotes do not protect whitespace; they are treated literally. Use an array in `bash`:

```
args=( "hi there" test)
./swap "${args[@]}"
```

In POSIX shell, you are stuck using `eval` (which is why most shells support arrays).

```
args='"hi there" test'
eval "./swap $args"
```

As usual, be *very* sure you know the contents of `$args` and understand how the resulting string will be parsed before using `eval`.

Comment: I would tend to argue that there are more options that `eval` here. Even in POSIX, one could read into `"$@"` from xargs.

Answer (score 2):

## Ugly Idea Alert: Pure Bash Function

Here's a quoted-string parser written in pure bash (what terrible fun)!

*Caveat*: just like the xargs example above, this errors in the case of an escaped quote. This could be fixed... but much better to do in an actual programming language.

### Example Usage

```sh
MY_ARGS="foo 'bar baz' qux * "'$(dangerous)'" sudo ls -lah"

# Create array from multi-line string
IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' args=($(parseargs "$MY_ARGS"))

# Show each of the arguments array
for arg in "${args[@]}"; do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

### Example Output

```
foo
bar baz
qux
*
```

### Parse Argument Function

This literally goes character-by-character and either adds to the current string or the current array.

```sh
set -u
set -e

# ParseArgs will parse a string that contains quoted strings the same as bash does
# (same as most other *nix shells do). This is secure in the sense that it doesn't do any
# executing or interpreting. However, it also doesn't do any escaping, so you shouldn't pass
# these strings to shells without escaping them.
parseargs() {
    notquote="-"
    str=$1
    declare -a args=()
    s=""

    # Strip leading space, then trailing space, then end with space.
    str="${str## }"
    str="${str%% }"
    str+=" "

    last_quote="${notquote}"
    is_space=""
    n=$(( ${#str} - 1 ))

    for ((i=0;i<=$n;i+=1)); do
        c="${str:$i:1}"

        # If we're ending a quote, break out and skip this character
        if [ "$c" == "$last_quote" ]; then
            last_quote=$notquote
            continue
        fi

        # If we're in a quote, count this character
        if [ "$last_quote" != "$notquote" ]; then
            s+=$c
            continue
        fi

        # If we encounter a quote, enter it and skip this character
        if [ "$c" == "'" ] || [ "$c" == '"' ]; then
            is_space=""
            last_quote=$c
            continue
        fi

        # If it's a space, store the string
        re="[[:space:]]+" # must be used as a var, not a literal
        if [[ $c =~ $re ]]; then
            if [ "0" == "$i" ] || [ -n "$is_space" ]; then
                echo continue $i $is_space
                continue
            fi
            is_space="true"
            args+=("$s")
            s=""
            continue
        fi

        is_space=""
        s+="$c"
    done

    if [ "$last_quote" != "$notquote" ]; then
        >&2 echo "error: quote not terminated"
        return 1
    fi

    for arg in "${args[@]}"; do
        echo "$arg"
    done
    return 0
}
```

I may or may not keep this updated at:

- https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/git-scripts/src/branch/master/git-proxy

Seems like a rather stupid thing to do... but I had the itch... oh well.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most robust approach, but it is simple, and seems to work for your case:

```
## demonstration matching the question
$ ( ARGS='"hi there" test' ; ./swap ${ARGS} )
there" "hi

## simple solution, using 'xargs'
$ ( ARGS='"hi there" test' ; echo ${ARGS} |xargs ./swap )
test hi there
```

Comment: Commentary: Bash string processing is extremely confusing.  `xargs` removes the guesswork by passing parameters directly via [`exec`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)), which bypasses the normal, capricious, string processing that Bash would otherwise perform as part of string-based command-line processing.

Comment: I can't be sure about my assertion regarding `exec`.  But I stand by my statement that **"Bash string processing is extremely confusing"**.

Comment: The processing done by `xargs` (when used without `-0` or the GNU extension `-d`) is _also_ fairly capricious, and while it's mostly shell-compatible, it's not 100% so. Also, `echo ${XARGS}` [has its own bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566), which vary depending on exactly which version of `echo` you're using; `printf '%s\n' "$XARGS"` [is more reliable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).

Comment: ("not 100% so" -- f/e, a backslash before a newline in xargs causes an error, whereas in shell it either makes the newline be ignored or makes it literal data, depending on context)