# scp multiple remote files while entering password once

Tags: linux, bash, scp

I'm trying to write a script to copy multiple files (in multiple directories) from a remote host to my local machine.

My script is (more or less) as follows:

```
path1="/home/db/primary/*.xml"
path2="/tmp/log_*"
copyto="/home/pathtodesktop/Desktop/temp"

mkdir $copyto

scpcommand="scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$address:\"$path1 $path2\" $copyto"
echo $scpcommand
$scpcommand
```

When I run the script, I get the following output:

```
scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@SERVER:"/home/db/primary/*.xml /tmp/log_*" /home/pathtodesktop/Desktop/temp
sh: syntax error: unterminated quoted string
cp: cannot stat '/tmp/log_*"': No such file or directory
```

The output of the echo is as expected. But when I copy the output above and run the command manually in the terminal, it works as expected with no errors.

So the ultimate question is, what am I doing wrong? The command seems to work fine when run manually in the terminal. Where is my syntax error?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a FAQ: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the link. This turned out to be the answer (but I can't mark it as such).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash Argument Escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067249/bash-argument-escaping)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `set -f` will prevent the wildcards in your paths from being expanded locally (although you may run in to other issues with spaces/special characters).

(You can re-enable wildcards afterwards with `set +f`)