# Bash: Read args from stdin into array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, arguments, lexical-analysis

## Problem Description

Given a plaintext file `args.in` containing one line of command line arguments, read them into an array.

## Problem Formulation

We have 4 files:

---

*args.in*:

```
"ab" c
```

---

*refimpl.sh*:

```
read -r line
bash -c "bash showargs.sh $line"
```

---

*arrayimpl.sh*:

```
arr=()

# BEGIN-------------------------
# Input comes from stdin.
# You need to set arr here.
# END---------------------------

echo "${#arr[@]}"
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

---

*showargs.sh*:

```
echo "$#"
for i in "$@"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

---

Put them into the same folder. We want you to implement `arrayimpl.sh` so that

```
bash refimpl.sh < args.in
```

and

```
bash arrayimpl.sh < args.in
```

give the same output.

Your solution should only contain a single file `arrayimpl.sh`.

## Output Example

```
2
ab
c
```

---

This problem is a better formulation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41316347/bash-split-quoted-string-into-array) but not a dup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067249/bash-reading-quoted-escaped-arguments-correctly-from-a-string). Some solutions work there but not here. For example, when we have the following input:

`args.in`:

```
"a\"b" c
```

There is no known solution yet.

Comment: @sorontar I want the scripts to read from stdin. So they are called like `./refimpl.sh < args.in`. That part has been fixed.

Comment: @StevenPenny Adding shebang here makes the question even longer. I think either way doesn't affect the result.

Comment: If input comes on the form like `"a b" c` on stdin, you can do  `eval "arr=( $(cat) )"`.

Comment: @thatotherguy Why don't you write an answer then? I tested with several inputs and it looks good. The only concern I have is about the potential risk of `eval` which is very difficult to harness.

Comment: There's is no risk or problem with using `eval` that `refimpl.sh` doesn't already have.

Comment: @Cyker Make the file `echo '"ab" c "d e" f\g *' > args.in` and try `eval "arr=( $(cat) )"` again. Thats an example of incorrect backslash quote removal and filename expansion. Just to name two problems.

Comment: @cyker, and to show how insecure, make args.in like this: `echo '"ab" c "d e" f\g * $(date)' > args.in` and either try `eval "arr=( $(cat) )"` or your `bash -c` idea. In short: **don't do that**.

Comment: @cyker Evan a quoted $(date) will execute: `echo '"$(date)"' > args.in; echo $(<args.in); eval "arr=( $(<args.in) )"; printf '<%s> ' "${arr[@]}"`.

Answer (score 2):

The expected solution for this assignment is something equivalent to:

```
eval "arr=( $(cat) )"
```

This evaluates input as shell words, which is what `refimpl.sh` also does.

This is for toy problems and homework assignments only. Real software should not use executable code as a data format.

Comment: I'm not near a computer, but it looks like it will work just like `refimpl.sh`, which is what OP is asking for.