# Bash: read filnames from file and check if it exist

Tags: bash

I want to read in from a file "filenames.dat" that contains the path + filenames of other files

```
$ more filenames.dat
"/home/test1.dat"
"/home/test2.dat"
"/home/test3.dat"
```

and then check if those files exist. This is the code for the first line in filenames.dat

```
line=$(head -n 1 "filenames.dat")
[ -e "$line" ] && echo "files do exist" || echo "files do not exist"
```

However I get "files do not exist" even if they do. If instead I do

```
[ -e "/home/test1.dat" ] && echo "files do exist" || echo "files do not exist"
```

than the file exists!

Comment: Quotes? What's the syntax of this file? JSON strings? Shell-quoted strings? Something else?

Comment: To be clear, your code is looking for a file named `"/home/test1.dat"`, not `/home/test1.dat`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so do I have to remove the quotes in filenames.dat?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067249/bash-reading-quoted-escaped-arguments-correctly-from-a-string for a detailed discussion.

Comment: That said, removing those literal quotes is indeed one way to fix this problem. If you want to *really* do things correctly, though, you're better off not using newline-delimited files to list names at all. (Keep in mind that filenames in UNIX are allowed to contain newline literals; if you have a file created with `touch $'foo\nbar'`, you can't put it in a newline-delimited filenames at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Literal* and *syntactic* quotes are two different things: The former tell the shell how to parse the code you enter, the latter are part of your data.

When you run:

```
echo '"filenames.dat"' >filenames.dat
line=$(head -n 1 "filenames.dat")
```

...the double quotes inside the line returned by `head` are *literal*: They're part of the data.

By contrast, in `[ -e "$line" ]`, the quotes there in the code are *syntactic*; they tell the shell to treat the results of the variable expansion as completely literal, without string-splitting or glob expansion. (This is correct and desirable).

When `[ -e "$line" ]` is run, then, what we check for existence is *the literal contents* of the variable named `line`. Because those literal contents include literal quotes returned by `head`, we the look for file and directory names that contain literal quotes.

Because your actual filenames don't contain literal quotes, the result is that the files are not found.

If you want to keep your data format as it is, with literal quotes in the data, follow the guidance in [Bash: Reading quoted/escaped arguments correctly from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067249/bash-reading-quoted-escaped-arguments-correctly-from-a-string)