# Expand shell glob in variable into array

Tags: bash, glob

In a bash script I have a variable containing a shell glob expression that I want to expand into an array of matching file names (`nullglob` turned on), like in

```
pat='dir/*.config'
files=($pat)
```

This works nicely, even for multiple patterns in `$pat` (e.g., `pat="dir/*.config dir/*.conf`), however, I cannot use escape characters in the pattern. Ideally, I would like to able to do

```
pat='"dir/*" dir/*.config "dir/file with spaces"'
```

to include the file `*`, all files ending in `.config` and `file with spaces`.

Is there an easy way to do this? (Without `eval` if possible.)

As the pattern is read from a file, I cannot place it in the array expression directly, [as proposed in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34012/261875) (and various other places).

**Edit:**

To put things into context: What I am trying to do is to read a template file line-wise and process all lines like `#include pattern`. The includes are then resolved using the shell glob. As this tool is meant to be universal, I want to be able to include files with spaces and weird characters (like `*`).

The "main" loop reads like this:

```
    template_include_pat='^#include (.*)$'
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        if printf '%s' "$line" | grep -qE "$template_include_pat"; then
            glob=$(printf '%s' "$line" | sed -nrE "s/$template_include_pat/\\1/p")
            cwd=$(pwd -P)
            cd "$targetdir"
            files=($glob)
            for f in "${files[@]}"; do
                printf "\n\n%s\n" "# FILE $f" >> "$tempfile"
                cat "$f" >> "$tempfile" ||
                    die "Cannot read '$f'."
            done
            cd "$cwd"
        else
            echo "$line" >> "$tempfile"
        fi
    done < "$template"
```

Comment: Another equivalent of `eval` : `source <(echo "files=($pat)")`

Comment: @anishsane: Saw that just now. Wondering why they wouldn't want to use it

Comment: @anubhava I am using [the tenique described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/5605853) to read files line-wise and then parse it with sed (I want to parse lines like '#include dir/*.config')

Comment: @anishsane Yeah, that works, but with the same security implications of eval... If Pattern is something like `$(echo GOTCHA >&2)` I certainly don't want to execute whats in `$(...)`.

Comment: This would fail if `pat` were something like `pat='dir a/*.config'`. Don't expect unquoted parameter expansions to ever do what you want.

Comment: You do realise that once you have dir/* all your other additions are already included, even you file with spaces

Comment: "same security implications of eval": Exactly. That's why I said, it's just equivalent of `eval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Python `glob` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Takes literal glob expressions on as argv; emits NUL-delimited match list on output
expand_globs() {
  python -c '
import sys, glob
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
  for result in glob.iglob(arg):
    sys.stdout.write("%s\0" % (result,))
' _ "$@"
}

template_include_pat='^#include (.*)$'
template=${1:-/dev/stdin}

# record the patterns we were looking for
patterns=( )

while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ $template_include_pat ]]; then
    patterns+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )
  fi
done <"$template"

results=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' name; do
  results+=( "$name" )
done < <(expand_globs "${patterns[@]}")

# Let's display our results:
{
  printf 'Searched for the following patterns, from template %q:\n' "$template"
  (( ${#patterns[@]} )) && printf ' - %q\n' "${patterns[@]}"
  echo
  echo "Found the following files:"
  (( ${#results[@]} )) && printf ' - %q\n' "${results[@]}"
} >&2
```

Comment: This is fine for relative pathes, but what about absolute ones? I.e. if the pattern reads `/etc/myconfig/*.config`...

Comment: Good point -- didn't realize that was covered. Amended to use the Python `glob` module instead.

Comment: Awesome, python is nice, too :)

Comment: I should probably start to write all my scripts in python... Thanks for your suggestion.

What is still left: Handling of quotes, i.e., literal match for patterns like `dir/the file.config`.

Comment: `#include dir/the file.config` should work (matching `the file.config`) as-is with no changes whatsoever.

Comment: If you *really* want to allow limited quoting/escaping, it's possible -- see my answer at [bash: reading quoted/escaped arguments correctly from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067249/bash-reading-quoted-escaped-arguments-correctly-from-a-string).

Comment: Yeah, I think python's shlex is the way to go. That way I can specify multiple globs on one line (separated with spaces) and match filenames with spaces. Although I doubt that I'll ever need to handle filenames with whitespace -- but who knows?

Comment: I only needed to expand files in the local directory (into an array), so I did `IFS=/ read -d $'\0' -a foo < <(python -c  'import sys, glob; print("/".join(glob.iglob(sys.argv[1])),end="");' "$d")` I'd have rather used NUL separation for more flexibility but IFS (like all shell variables) does not support that.  Creating the array syntax in python would probably be the next obvious step if I wanted to support directories.

Comment: @SethRobertson, `while IFS= read -r -d '' foo; do arr+=( "$foo" ); done < <(...)` lets you read NUL-delimited content into a shell array straightforwardly enough -- and there are newer equivalents (`readarray -d '' arr`) if you're able to be compatible with only current bash releases.