# Executing a command (read from an external file) containing Double quoted parameters

Tags: bash, scripting, double-quotes

Let's say I have a *file.txt* file like this:

```
some words
from here
blah blah blah
that begins
this is this

to here
other content
```

and another file called *config.conf" like this:

```
name1:value1
name2:value2    
expr:sed -re "s/this/that/g" -ne "/from here/,/to here/ p"
name3:value3
name4:value4
```

In my *script.sh* I need to get the whole sed command that is written after "expr:" in the *config.conf* and execute it in a pipe like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

pipecommand=$(cat info | grep -e "^expr:" | sed -re "s/^expr://g")
cat file.txt | $pipecommand > output.file
```

but I get this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'
```

I've read about many similar questions here and the solution was using an array like this:

```
pipecommand=($(cat info | grep -e "^expr:" | sed -re "s/^expr://g"))
cat file.txt | ${pipecommand[@]} > output.file
```

Unfortunately this works only with less complex commands and only if I assign the "sed...blah blah blah" command directly to the variable, without reading it from a file.

Do some of you know a working solution to this?

P.S.: I can change both the *script.sh* and the *config.conf* files.

Comment: Config files don't contain code. You have a poorly designed library.

Comment: The text refers to `config.conf` but the code uses `info`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your config file into a plugin with a well-defined interface. Here, your script expects a function named `sed_wrapper`, so you provide a definition with that name in your "config file" (renamed to `lib.sh` here).

```
# This is lib.sh
sed_wrapper () {
    sed -re "s/this/that/g" -ne "/from here/,/to here/ p"
}
```

Then, in your script, call the named function.

```
. lib.sh

sed_wrapper < file.txt > output.file
```

Comment: Thanks man! At the end I needed to completely change everything due to client's needs, but I'm using this kind of approach in the new version.

Answer (score 3):

Interpreting this as a question about how to apply the advice from [Reading quoted/escaped arguments correctly from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067249/reading-quoted-escaped-arguments-correctly-from-a-string) to your use case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# the sed expression here is modified to work with BSD sed, not only GNU sed
pipecommand=$(sed -ne 's/^expr://p' <info)

array=( )
while IFS= read -r -d ''; do
  array+=( "$REPLY" )
done < <(xargs printf '%s\0' <<<"$pipecommand")

<file.txt "${array[@]}" > output.file
```

This safer than `eval`, insofar as the words inside your `expr:` can be treated only as literal arguments, and can't be parsed as redirections, substitutions, parameter expansions, or other shell syntax. Of course, an expr of `sh -c '...'` can be used to enable shell syntax inside the `...` section: Constraining the command (the first element of the array) is necessary if you genuinely wanted to sandbox, control or constrain the invoked command.

Comment: The `sed` command seems excessively complicated.  What is wrong with `sed -n 's/^expr://p' info`?

Comment: @pjh, that's indeed much better -- the idioms in my head are GNUisms, and I ended up with that overcomplicated version when trying to build something that would work on BSD.

Comment: Note that `bash` and `xargs` don't handle quotes in the same way, so this solution fails in some situations where an `eval`-based solution may succeed.  Try, for example, a configuration file containing `expr:sed "s/\"/'/g"` (which tries to replace double quotes with single quotes).

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, you need eval.

```
pipecommand=$(grep "^expr:" info | cut -d: -f2-)
eval "$pipecommand" <file.txt > output.file
```

Try to avoid eval.

Comment: ... and `cat` on a single file, and `grep` when you are using `sed` anyway. These are only [useless.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) though, not evil like `eval`.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk: I'd like to avoid eval but at the moment your solution is the only one I tried that works...

Comment: You don't "need" `eval` (see other solutions), but it provides a simple and effective solution.  Given that the program is intended to run arbitrary code read from a file, using `eval` doesn't make the (very bad) situation much worse than it is already.