# Veeam CLI Unknown Argument when Passing Arguments in Bash Script

Tags: bash, veeam

I'm writing a bash script to call functions of the Veeam Backup CLI.

In this script I have a function to configure a new backup job.

```
function configureBackupJob() {

    jobname="$1"
    reponame="$2"
    objects="$3"
    advancedOptions="$4"
    scheduleOptions="$5"
    activeFullBackupOptions="$6"
    indexingOptions="$7"


    command="veeamconfig job create filelevel --name ${jobname} --reponame ${reponame} --includedirs ${objects} ${advancedOptions} ${scheduleOptions} ${activeFullBackupOptions} ${indexingOptions} --nosnap"
    echo "${command}"

    veeamconfig job create filelevel --name "$jobname" --reponame "$reponame" --includedirs "$objects" "$advancedOptions" "$scheduleOptions" "$activeFullBackupOptions" "$indexingOptions" --nosnap
```

}

When calling the script I use a case to determine which function shall be called:

```
case $command in
    # More cases before and after this one
    configureBackupJob)
        configureBackupJob "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8"
        ;;
    *)
        showHelp
        ;;
esac
```

I call the script like this:

```
sudo ./script.sh configureBackupJob "TheJobsName" "RepositoryName" "/path/FoldertoBeBackedUpByVeeam"  "--daily --at 12:15" "--weekdays-full Monday,Wednesday" "--indexall"
```

I used this site from the Veeam help center to know the arguments: [Veeam Help Center: Creating File-Level Backup Job](https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/agentforlinux/userguide/backup_job_create_file-level.html?ver=40)

Calling the script results in an error message

```
Unknown argument: [--daily --at 12:15].
```

If I call veeamconfig manually the command that my echo shows works fine.

Why can I call the command directly but not from within the script? I tried calling the function without the double quotation marks but that doesn't work.

I can't hardcode all arguments like the

```
--includedirs
```

so I need to find a way to pass arguments like the

```
--daily --at 12:15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that you're passing "`--daily --at 12:15`" to the `veeamconfig` command as a single argument, rather than three separate arguments ("`--daily`", "`--at`", and "`12:15`"). This confuses `veeamconfig`. It looks ok when you `echo` it because that looses the distinction *between* spaces between arguments and spaces *within* arguments.

The best way to handle this depends on a couple of things: First, does your script care which options have to do with scheduling vs indexing vs full backups vs whatever, or is it ok if there's just a list of options to be given to the `veeamconfig` command? Second, is it possible that the paths/options/whatever might contain spaces (or filename wildcards) *in* them, as well as between them? (Note: I mostly use macOS, where paths with spaces are very common.)

If the script doesn't have to differentiate between the different types of options, it's pretty simple: just pass all of the options as separate arguments all the way through, and where necessary store them as an array rather than as separate strings (and use bash `printf`'s `%q` option to properly quote/escape the command options for printing):

```
function configureBackupJob() {

    jobname="$1"
    reponame="$2"
    object="$3"
    allOptions=("${@:4}")    # This stores all arguments starting with $4 in an array

    printf -v command '%q ' veeamconfig job create filelevel --name "$jobname" --reponame "$reponame" --includedirs "$object" "${allOptions[@]}" --nosnap
    echo "${command}"

    veeamconfig job create filelevel --name "$jobname" --reponame "$reponame" --includedirs "$object" "${allOptions[@]}" --nosnap
}
```

And call it like this:

```
case $command in
    # More cases before and after this one
    configureBackupJob)
        configureBackupJob "${@:2}"
        ...
```

And run the overall script like this:

```
sudo ./script.sh configureBackupJob "TheJobsName" "RepositoryName" "/path/FoldertoBeBackedUpByVeeam"  --daily --at 12:15 --weekdays-full Monday,Wednesday --indexall
```

If the script needs to tell the different types of option apart, things get messier. If there's no possibility of spaces or wildcard-like characters in the options, you could leave those variables unquoted when you pass them to the `veeamconfig` command, and let the shell's word splitting break them up into individual arguments:

```
veeamconfig job create filelevel --name "$jobname" --reponame "$reponame" --includedirs "$objects" $advancedOptions $scheduleOptions $activeFullBackupOptions $indexingOptions --nosnap
```

Note that if you go this route, you need to keep them safely double-quoted at all other points in the process, especially when passing them to the `configureBackupJob` function. If word-splitting happens too early, it'll just make a mess.

If you need to keep types of options separate *and* also allow spaces and/or funny characters in the options, it's even more difficult. You might be tempted to put quotes and/or escapes within the options to control this, but word splitting doesn't respect those, so it doesn't work. I think I'll just refer you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067249/reading-quoted-escaped-arguments-correctly-from-a-string) and hope this doesn't apply.

Comment: The first solution worked perfectly! Your help is greatly appreciated Gordon, thank you very much!