# How to only do quote removal in a shell?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

Given a string from an untrusted source, e.g.

```
MALICIOUS_INPUT="$(awk -F = '/^VERSION=/ {print $2}' /path/to/compromised/etc/os-release | head -n 1)"
```

is it possible to just apply pure shell quote removal (see [Shell Command Language (IEEE Std 1003.1-2017)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_07) and [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal)) to that string i.e. without doing variable expansions, arithmetic expansions, command substitution and similar?

This is needed, for example to parse strings from [os-release](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html) files without `source`-ing the files.

| Input | Expected result |
| --- | --- |
| `'\"'` | `\"` |
| `"\""` | `"` |
| `'$foo${foo}$(pwd)$((1+2))'` | `$foo${foo}$(pwd)$((1+2))` |
| `"$foo${foo}$(pwd)$((1+2))"` | `$foo${foo}$(pwd)$((1+2))` |

Comment: The easy answer here is to drop to a non-bash language; Python's `shlex.split()` does only quote removing and word-splitting.

Comment: `xargs` can also be leveraged to do _almost_, but not quite, shell-compatible parsing. (The corner cases are annoying, but if you run into them, you know the input is hostile -- no legitimate `/etc/os-release` will be containing multi-line strings or the like). Also, I'm quite sure I've already described the technique (as well as the use of Python's `shlex` module for the same purpose) in existing Q&A entries here.

Comment: ...here we are: [Reading quoted/escaped arguments correctly from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31485948/14122)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing applicability of the preexisting answers on [Reading quoted/escaped arguments correctly from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067249/reading-quoted-escaped-arguments-correctly-from-a-string/31485948#31485948) to this question:

```
parse_with_xargs() {
  xargs printf '%s\0' <<<"$*"
}

parse_with_python() {
  python -c '
import shlex, sys
for item in shlex.split(sys.stdin.read()):
    sys.stdout.write(item + "\0")
' <<<"$*"
}

readarray -t example_lines <<'EOF'
'\"'
"\""
'$foo${foo}$(pwd)$((1+2))'
"$foo${foo}$(pwd)$((1+2))"  
EOF

for line in "${example_lines[@]}"; do
  printf 'Input line:         %s\n' "$line"
  printf 'Parsed with xargs:  '; parse_with_xargs "$line" 2>&1; echo
  printf 'Parsed with python: '; parse_with_python "$line" 2>&1; echo
  echo
done
```

---

Output:

```
Input line:         '\"'
Parsed with xargs:  \"
Parsed with python: \"

Input line:         "\""
Parsed with xargs:  xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option

Parsed with python: "

Input line:         '$foo${foo}$(pwd)$((1+2))'
Parsed with xargs:  $foo${foo}$(pwd)$((1+2))
Parsed with python: $foo${foo}$(pwd)$((1+2))

Input line:         "$foo${foo}$(pwd)$((1+2))"  
Parsed with xargs:  $foo${foo}$(pwd)$((1+2))
Parsed with python: $foo${foo}$(pwd)$((1+2))
```