# Pass bash variable with quotes as argument

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, quoting

I have a variable:

```sh
var='aaa bbb "ccc ddd"'
```

And the following argument-printing `./script.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for arg in "$@"; do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

Expected outcome:

```sh
$ ./script.sh $var
aaa
bbb
ccc ddd
```

Actual outcome:

```sh
$ ./script.sh $var
aaa
bbb
"ccc
ddd"
$ ./script.sh "$var"
aaa bbb "ccc ddd"
$ ./script.sh ${var@Q}
'aaa
bbb
"ccc
ddd"'
```

Is there a way to make it happen?

I don't have control over `$var` - it can't be an array, for example.

Comment: How would the content of `var` look like, if it were an array? You need to give an example at least, similar as you provided it for the scalar. Also it is not clear what the expected outcome should be for `var="aaa bbb 'ccc ddd'"` or `var='aaa bbb \`ccc ddd\`'`. You would need to define, what quotes are allowed inside of `var`.

Comment: As an array it's simple: `arr=(aaa bbb "ccc ddd")`, `./script.sh "${arr[@]}"`. My point was, it can not be an array, I get `$var` as a given and need to work with it

Comment: Sorry,misread your question in this point. Still, you need to clarify the other issues I mentioned. Also, it would be important to know what other characters can appear inside `var`. For instance, are there only letters and spaces and quotes?

Comment: `var` is what it is. I have no control over it. I want to pass it to `./script.sh`, using some bash-quoting-voodoo-magic, in a way that will give me the expected output. I want to to work as if I did `./script aaa bbb "ccc ddd"`, but using `var` instead of the explicit arguments.

Comment: Here are some previous questions may be relevant: ["Reading quoted/escaped arguments correctly from a string"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067249/reading-quoted-escaped-arguments-correctly-from-a-string) and ["Get bash to respect quotes when word splitting subshell output"](https://superuser.com/questions/1529226/get-bash-to-respect-quotes-when-word-splitting-subshell-output).

Comment: @koorkevani : You need to know at least, what the content of the variable can be, i.e. need somehow have a grammar for it. Otherwise you can't write a parser, or decide, which existing parser (`eval`, `xargs`, ...) would do what you want.

Comment: @user1934428 my example was pretty much as complex as it gets. I believe `xargs` will do

Comment: The problem is how bash interprets your input. Once you use unquoted $var, it will be spit into 4 values:
aaa
bbb
"ccc
ddd"
The quotation Marks will not get interpreted. To force it to do so, you would need
to do a 
eval ./script.sh $var
But this is dangerous and should never be used with variables you don't know!
You would need to interpret the parameters handed over to your script and interpret quotation marks to do it the correct way ...

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!

```sh
$ echo "$var" | xargs ./script
aaa
bbb
ccc ddd
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: If you set `var='aaa bbb ccc ddd"'` (i.e. the first double quote omitted), do you still get the result you expect?

Comment: xargs exits with code 1, which I guess is what I expect from a parsing error. It does run `./script.sh` with all the well-formatted arguments, which is not ideal, but in my case `$var` is trusted, so either way it's not a problem