# How to re-write this bash method without using "eval"

Tags: bash

Here is a script newbie question.  I am invoking a script as follows (not space in `hello world`):

```
$ ALL_ARGS="-t 30 -h 'hello world'" ./test.sh
```

Inside `test.sh` I would like to pass the parameters in ALL_ARGS as 4 separate parameters, but without using the 'eval' call.

```
#!/bin/bash

#my_function should receive 4 parameters
#

my_function () { 
    printf "'%s' " "$1"
    printf "'%s' " "$2"
    printf "'%s' " "$3"
    printf "'%s' " "$4"
    echo ""
}

echo "Desired Output, but without using eval"
# my_function '-t' '30' '-h' 'hello world'
eval "my_function $(echo $ALL_ARGS)"
```

As you can see, I am calling `my_function` from inside my script and passing in the value of `$ALL_ARGS`.  The problem is the "space" in the `$ALL_ARGS`.  The following attempts have failed, for various reasons:

```
my_function $(echo $ALL_ARGS)
my_function $(echo "$ALL_ARGS")
my_function "$(echo "$ALL_ARGS")"
my_function "$(echo $ALL_ARGS)"
my_function "$ALL_ARGS"
my_function $ALL_ARGS
```

In essence, I want the call to look something like this when it executes in the script:

```
my_function -t 30 -h 'hello world'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Let me see if I understand: You want to provide multiple configuration commands and a main arguments at the end, right?

Comment: Arrays were introduced as a replacement for trying to use regular parameters to store lists of distinct values. Unfortunately, you can't export an array as an environment variable (at least, not without destroying the structure arrays provide in the first place).

Comment: See [Reading quoted/escaped arguments correctly from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067249/reading-quoted-escaped-arguments-correctly-from-a-string) (which I've added to the list of linked duplicates)

Comment: BTW, note that `printf "'%s' " "$1"` is very much not sufficient to make data eval-safe. Consider what it does if your `$1` is `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'`, with literal `'`s as part of the data.