# Expand bash array with globbing and extra words

Tags: bash, variables, variable-expansion

In a CI/CD job, I have a shell variable `X` defined.  It contains one or more words, each of which might have glob operators:

```
X="foo bar* 'a b c'"
```

Suppose `bar*` matches 3 files, `bard`, `bare`, and `barf`.  And the file `a b c` exists and has 2 spaces in it.

I want to create a Bash array `Y` with these contents:

```
Y=(--arg foo --arg bard --arg bare --arg barf --arg 'a b c')
```

In other words: do glob/quote expansion, then map each word `w` to `--arg $w`.

A clean solution would allow spaces in the expanded names (to be honest, I'm never going to have that situation in this CI/CD code - but I or someone else might easily copy/paste this technique somewhere else where it does matter).

It would also be awesome if I could do glob/quote expansion *without* invoking all other possible shell expansions (e.g. process substitution & subshells) - I'm having trouble thinking of how to do that, though.

The only solution I've come up with so far is to use unprotected expansion:

```
Y=()
for a in $X; do
    Y+=(--arg "$a")
done
```

Is that the best I can do?  Is it safe?  It works well on the `foo` and `bar*` cases, but not well on the `a b c` case.

Comment: I think this is difficult. I don't think there's a way to do wildcard expansion that doesn't also do word splitting.

Comment: Just realized my example is wrong - it assumes `X` is an array, which it's not.  I'll fix that.

Comment: The only other expansion that's done is word splitting. But it doesn't split within the words of a filename that came from glob expansion. So your loop should work.

Comment: The only problem is if you want to match a file named `foo bar1`. You can't have it both ways, either the space in `X` separates wildcards, or it should be ignored and treated as part of the wildcard.

Comment: You could change `IFS` to just a single character (e.g. `IFS=$'\n'` for newline), and then use that as a delimiter in the pattern string -- that'd work as long as you never need to include that character in a pattern. (But be sure to set `IFS` back to normal afterward, to avoid weird effects later in the script.)

Comment: Thanks, I have this working for all the *reasonable* cases now, but I'm adding one more case with spaces in filenames to the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand globs while honoring quotes (for grouping but not glob-suppression), but *not* expand variables or handle process substitutions or other dangerous syntax...

```
X="foo bar* 'a b c'"

IFS=
args=( )
while read -r -d '' word; do
  for item in $word; do
    args+=( --arg "$item" )
  done
done < <(xargs printf '%s\0' <<<"$X")
```

See this running in an online sandbox (where `bard`, `bare` and `barf` exist) at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/UnlawfulDecentApplicationserver#main.sh

The use of `xargs printf '%s\0'` has `xargs` do the work of word-splitting in an *almost* POSIX-compliant way (if you want something completely POSIX-compliant, you need to use the Python `shlex` module instead -- [other Q&A on the site demonstrates how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31485948/14122)), and the unquoted expansion with an empty IFS performs globbing only.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `declare` which has `eval` capabilities:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

x="foo bar* 'a b c'"
declare -a x="($x)"

y=()
for a in "${x[@]}"; do y+=(--arg "$a"); done
```

Now it comes down to what you would like, for example, `x='$HOME \  \$USER $( ls )'` to really represent...

Answer (score 1):

Take @Fravadona's answer over this one.

---

You have to trust that nothing malicious is going to be in that string.

This is a case where you need `eval`: given

```sh
$ touch bar{d,e,f}
$ X="foo bar* 'a b c'"
```

then this won't get you what you want:

```sh
$ y=($X)
$ declare -p y
declare -a y=([0]="foo" [1]="bard" [2]="bare" [3]="barf" [4]="'a" [5]="b" [6]="c'")
```

however

```sh
$ eval "y=($X)"
$ declare -p y
declare -a y=([0]="foo" [1]="bard" [2]="bare" [3]="barf" [4]="a b c")
```

then

```sh
$ Y=(); for elem in "${y[@]}"; do Y+=(--arg "$elem"); done
$ declare -p Y
declare -a Y=([0]="--arg" [1]="foo" [2]="--arg" [3]="bard" [4]="--arg" [5]="bare" [6]="--arg" [7]="barf" [8]="--arg" [9]="a b c")
```

If you have a bad actor, and you get `X='nasty $(bad command here)'`, then you cannot use eval.