# Bash, iterate over the words in a variable with white spaces

Tags: bash, whitespace

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

fruits="apple \"orange juice\" banana"

IFS=" " read -a words <<< "$fruits"
for word in "${words[@]}"
do
    echo "Word: $word"
done
```

Which produces the following:

```
Word: apple
Word: "orange
Word: juice"
Word: banana
```

It splits the sentence "orange juice" into two words. I want to achieve the following output:

```
Word: apple
Word: orange juice
Word: banana
```

But I am unable to make it work as I want. What's the problem here?

The following works as expected:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

for word in apple "orange juice" banana
do
    echo "Word: $word"
done
```

So I was expecting that the array expansion with `"${words[@]}"` did the trick, but it doesn't work. Any idea? thanks!

Comment: See ["Reading quoted/escaped arguments correctly from a string"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067249/reading-quoted-escaped-arguments-correctly-from-a-string) and the Superuser question ["Get bash to respect quotes when word splitting subshell output"](https://superuser.com/questions/1529226/get-bash-to-respect-quotes-when-word-splitting-subshell-output).

Comment: Silly question: Does the original data have to be a string? Can't it be an array?

Comment: No silly question, this is a simplification of a script I am working on. The data can be supplied by any user using a variable, e.g JAVA_OPTS. I have to process it, so it can't be an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Your shebang `#!/bin/sh` indicates POSIX sh. This conflicts with the use of here-strings and arrays. You may want to change it to `#!/bin/bash` (in conformance with the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) tag you've selected for this question).

That said, the intended encoding of your input string seems to be compatible with how bash expects encoding the definition of an indexed array, only short of the parens around it. Whether other instances would do as well is not obvious from that single example, but it's worth giving the use of `declare -a` a try.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

fruits="apple \"orange juice\" banana"

declare -a words="($fruits)"
for word in "${words[@]}"
do
    echo "Word: $word"
done
```

```
Word: apple
Word: orange juice
Word: banana
```

Comment: But then why would you put them in a cumbersome string and then immediately convert it into an array, instead of just storing the values in an array in the first place?

Comment: @tripleee I assumed that the source for the string's content is outside of this script, and is declered here within the script just for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Correct on the assumption. This is a simplified version of a script I am working on. The values I am trying to parse correctly come from a variable that can be initialized by a user, e.g JAVA_OPTS

Answer (score 0):

When you ask bash to split a string on spaces that's what it will do. It has no idea that you only want *some* spaces treated as separators.

---

Because some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”, here's a way to split your string using bash's `=~` operator:

```
parse(){
    local -n in=$1 out=$2 b=BASH_REMATCH
    local s=$in a=()

    while [[ $s =~ \"([^\"]+)\"|([^[:space:]]+) ]]; do
        a+=("${b[1]}${b[2]}")
        s=${s#*"$b"}
    done
    out=("${a[@]}")
}
```

Use as:

```
fruits="apple \"orange juice\" banana"

parse fruits words
```

Then `words` contains the pieces:

```
$ declare -p words
declare -a words=([0]="apple" [1]="orange juice" [2]="banana")
$
```

Comment: this code doesn't handle escaped double-quotes