# bash get correct expansion of a variable in a for

Tags: bash

With something like:

```
for i in a1 'a2 a3'
do
  echo ${i}
done
```

I get it correctly:

```
a1
a2 a3
```

While by putting `a1 'a2 a3'` in a variable I'm not able to get it working

```
VAR="a1 'a2 a3'"

for i in ${VAR}
do
  echo ${i}
done
```

What's the way to declare `VAR` or use it in the `for` statement?

Comment: Use shell array to store multiple values

Comment: The shell parses quotes and escapes before expanding variables, so putting quotes or escapes (or most other shell syntax) in variables doesn't do anything useful. See ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia) and [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: It only *looks* correct for this example. Add more whitespace to `'a2 a3'` and you'll see a difference. `${i}` must be quoted to preserve the actual value of `i`, and short of hard-to-read and harder-to-write-safely `eval` hacks, there's no way to do what you want without an array. (Which is why arrays have been added to virtually every POSIX-based shell, and last I heard POSIX is considering adding arrays to its shell specification, though I don't know what the status of that effort is.)

Answer (score 6):

Using a proper *array*:

```
arr=( a1 'a2 a3' )

for a in "${arr[@]}"; do
  echo "$a"
done
```

Check how I add double quotes around variables ¹

---

An array maps numbers to strings. Bash >= 4 also has associative arrays (maps strings to strings).
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Arrays
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays

---

¹ Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> https://web.archive.org/web/20230224010517/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary

Comment: ++ for suggesting arrays

Comment: I'm sorry but I added the wrong example.
The real case is when VAR is already part of an array, like VAR[1]="a1 'a2 a3'" so VAR[1]=( a 'b c') won't work

Comment: Just post another question. Never change a question having answer that fits your initial needs (respect for people giving time). It will be costless to post new one

Comment: @justin8976 See ["Reading quoted/escaped arguments correctly from a string"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067249/reading-quoted-escaped-arguments-correctly-from-a-string) and ["Get bash to respect quotes when word splitting subshell output"](https://superuser.com/questions/1529226/get-bash-to-respect-quotes-when-word-splitting-subshell-output).

Answer (score 1):

*If* you can overwrite the positional parameters, you can use them as a pseudo-array in any POSIX-compatible shell.

```
set -- a1 'a2   a3'  # Replaces VAR with the special parameter @
for i in "$@"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

outputs

```
a1
a2   a3
```

(Note the preservation of multiple spaces in the second value of `i`.)