# bash get correct expansion of an array member in a for

Tags: bash, scripting

I have an array that contains a list of commands, and I want to execute them one by one by cycling over them in a `for` loop.
However when the command is a single word, it works as expected while when there is an argument it does not.

```
VAR[0]="ls"
VAR[1]="ls -la"

for i in ${VAR[@]}
do
    ${i}
done
```

I need also (if possible) to bind multiple commands in the same VAR, like: `VAR[1]="ls -la ; ls -ltr"`

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds a serious problem in the code (missing quotes).  The report that it produces includes a link to more information about the problem and how to fix it.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: [Variables hold data. Functions hold code. Don't put code inside variables!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). That applies whether the variables are scalar or arrays. Also, don't use all upper case for non-exported variable names, see [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).

Comment: All the advice you're getting here you already got when you asked [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77993300/1745001).

Comment: If you [edit] your question to explain **what** you're trying to do (which includes why you think you need to populate an array with `ls` and `ls -a` and then execute the array's contents in a loop instead of just calling `ls` then `ls -la`) rather than just **how** you're trying to do it (i.e. by storing multiple commands in an array) then we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Comment: Classic example of an [X/Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ Please ask the REAL question - explain what you are trying to accomplish, and *read the [BashFAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) link* people have posted *several* times (and probably the rest of the whole BashFAQ site, it's a gold mine.) Also, rather than reposting your question reworded, go and edit your original question, and follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to asking well so that you get good, helpful, *useful* answers. Good luck!

Comment: You might be happy with `commands=( 'ls' 'ls -la; ls -ltr' ); for cmd in "${commands[@]}"; do eval "$cmd"; done `.  You probably shouldn't be though.  See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: ***Don't do this.***

The quickest example of why this *isn't* working is that your variable is *data*, and when you drop it on the command line to be parsed as code, not all of it gets passed the way you think.

A simplified example:

```
$: cat x
#! /bin/bash -x
code=" cat x ; ls -l x > y "
$code

$: ./x
+ code=' cat x ; ls -l x > y '
+ cat x ';' ls -l x '>' y
cat: unknown option -- l
Try 'cat --help' for more information.
```

What's happening here? I successfully `cat` the file, then when I run it the first command in the `code` *variable* is to `cat` the file. Why didn't it work?

See the debugging output from the `-x`: what actually got parsed from the *variable* and passed to the interpreter was
`cat x ';' ls -l x '>' y`

That's the `cat` command, followed by the *argument list* of inputs:

- the file `x`
- the file `';'` (which does not exist...)
- the file `ls`  (which also does not exist...)
- the behavior-flag argument `-l`
- the file `x`   (again)
- the file `'>'` (which also does not exist...)
- the file `y`   (which also does not exist...)

*Wait, what?*
That's right, the semicolon is a metacharacter that the parser should use to delimit the `cat` command as ended. Since you put it in a variable, it's now part of the *data* just as if you had enclosed it in single quotes, which is how the debugger represented it. The same thing happened with the output redirection.

That means *all* the tokens got passed as arguments to `cat`, and since it doesn't have a `-l` option it choked and crashed.

This is just one of MANY, *MANY* things that can go wrong when you do this, and some of them are *really* hard to prevent, so just ... don't.

PLEASE go read the [BashFAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) people have been linking, and understand why you do not want to do this.

Edit your question to explain what it is you are actually trying to *accomplish*, and we'll help you figure out a way to do it that *isn't* stuffing code into variables.

Answer (score 1):

You need more quotes!

```
VAR[0]="ls"
VAR[1]="ls -la"

for i in "${VAR[@]}"
do
    $i
done
```

---

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> [wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words](https://web.archive.org/web/20230224010517/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words)
> [unix.stackexchange.com/when-is-double-quoting-necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

---

But, bash FAQ#50 said:

> I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!

Variables hold data. Functions hold code. Don't put code inside variables! There are many situations in which people try to shove commands, or command arguments, into variables and then run them. Each case needs to be handled separately.

https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: It does not work. What I asked is have a list of commands in the same VAR like `VAR[1]="ls -la ; ls -ltr"`

Comment: **Don't use variables to store commands**. Read again all of my post.